# Java library for extracting metadata

Tags: file, metadata, libraries

I have a binary file which has an ASCII metadata header. The elements are of the form "tag = value". Do you know of any Java libraries that will simplify extraction of this metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`Properties`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html). Its `load` and `store` methods use a format very similar to the one you described.